# HighCharts - Make labels appear dynamically based on column size

Tags: dynamic, highcharts, label, column-chart, column-sizing

I want to make the label to appear dynamically based on the size of the column.

For example if the column is smaller than 2px no label should appear. I dont want it to be based upon the value. I want it to be based upon the actual pixel size of the column.

Where is says if(this.y == 30) I want it to say something like if(column.height == 2)

```
dataLabels: 
            {
                enabled: true,
                formatter:function() 
                {

                    if(this.y == 30)
                    {
                    return ''
                   }
                   else{
                   return this.y + '%';

                    }
                }
```

my fidle below:
http://jsfiddle.net/Malvinator/2t0r3am5/

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this solution and works, have used 40 to test on your fiddle but can change that to the desired pixel height

```
formatter: function() {
    if (this.point.shapeArgs.height < 40) {
        return ''
    } else {
        return this.y + '%'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfect. I used it on Waterfall and on stacked columns for Jaspersoft graphs. Exactly what I was looking for.